# pyopencl erro : LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed: <unknown error -1001>

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencl, anaconda, pyopencl

When I run a Python script, I get an error:

> LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed:

I install anaconda and conda-forge package pyopencl.

```
LogicError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/inat/Git/xrt/tests/raycing/info_opencl.py in <module>()
      2 
      3 print('\n' + '=' * 60 + '\nOpenCL Platforms and Devices')
----> 4 for platform in cl.get_platforms():  # Print each platform on this computer
      5     print('=' * 60)
      6     print('Platform - Name:  ' + platform.name)

/home/inat/APP/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyopencl/cffi_cl.py in get_platforms()
    661 def get_platforms():
    662     platforms = _CArray(_ffi.new('clobj_t**'))
--> 663     _handle_error(_lib.get_platforms(platforms.ptr, platforms.size))
    664     return [Platform._create(platforms.ptr[0][i])
    665             for i in range(platforms.size[0])]

/home/inat/APP/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyopencl/cffi_cl.py in _handle_error(error)
    623     _lib.free_pointer(error.msg)
    624     _lib.free_pointer(error)
--> 625     raise e
    626 
    627 # }}}

LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed: <unknown error -1001>
```

Comment: I'd guess that there is something wrong with Your drivers. Could You please clarify, what platform and set of hardware are You using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 
model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4150 CPU @ 3.50GHz
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

Comment: OpenCL driver? Do You have Your [beignet](https://01.org/beignet) installation set-up?

Comment: I don't have beignet? what's that? I install a SDK of intel.